# Iterative MenuLayer Pebble

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I am trying to create an app on pebble using MenuLayer. My intention is to create Menu's and then sub-menus using the MenuLayer.

I did some basic implementation using "menu_layer_set_callbacks" method and registering callbacks methods for each submenu layers. However, now I realise its getting too messy.

I want to know if there is any easy way out provided in the framework to meet this requirement.

Thanks.

KK

Comment: Please show us some code, as it stands this is a very low quality question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you ended up with, but for my project, I made a set of sub-windows but reuses the same callbacks, you can pass custom data to let each know what type it is. Then just push the required sub-windows as needed

```
void sub_window_load(Window* parentWindow) {
  Layer* window_layer = window_get_root_layer(parentWindow);
  const GRect bounds = layer_get_frame(window_layer);

  MenuLayer* new_layer = menu_layer_create(bounds);
  const int context = *((int*) window_get_user_data(parentWindow));

  if (context == ID_A)      s_A_layer = new_layer;
  else if (context == ID_B) s_B_layer = new_layer;

  menu_layer_set_callbacks(new_layer, window_get_user_data(parentWindow), (MenuLayerCallbacks){
    .get_num_sections = sub_menu_get_num_sections_callback,
    .get_num_rows = sub_menu_get_num_rows_callback
    /* etc */
  });
  menu_layer_set_click_config_onto_window(new_layer, parentWindow);
  layer_add_child(window_layer, menu_layer_get_layer(new_layer));
}

void createSubWin(Window** w, int* context) {
  *w = window_create();
  window_set_user_data(*w, context);
  window_set_window_handlers(*w, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = sub_window_load,
    .unload = sub_window_unload
  }); 
}
```